# Can't view extended attributes of a directory in MacOs Sonoma with xattr, even though they are flagged in the directory listing

Tags: macos, terminal, extended-attributes

When I do an `ls -lg` of my user directory I can see a file directory called:

`drwx------+ 33 staff  1056 Oct 19 11:09 Movies`

Which, as you can see, has a plus sign at the end of the permissions, signalling that it has extended attributes.

However if I try

`xattr Movies`

I get nothing as output. Why might that be?

Answer (score 3):

Extended Attributes are represented by `@`, not `+`.

The plus sign indicates ACLs, which you'll see with `ls -le`:

```
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

You can see extended attributes with `ls -l@`.

According to the `man` page for `ls`, the `-g` flag has no effect.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the correct answer. Yes, I saw ls -g flag in man, but it does actually have an effect: It only displays the group and not the user in a directory listing, which can be useful if you'd rather not share your username in a screenshot for example.

Comment: @knicknack There's very little security risk in revealing your username, even if I already knew your IP address. (Particularly if it's just something like "Bob".) Even if I had physical access, I could probably see it on the login screen, but it wouldn't do me much good beyond that. Perhaps I might be able to do something if you used the same name and password for some website that gets hacked.  Anyway: do accept the answer as correct, if you're happy with it.

Comment: @benwigley. "Anyway: do accept the answer as correct, if you're happy with it." Is that an actual action I have to do? Don't see an option anywhere... I voted it as useful, is there something else that needs to be done? - sorry, new here :o)

Comment: @knicknack There should be a tick.